# Getting error in SQL Server executing get-wmiobject

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to execute following PowerShell query in SQL Server

```
xp_cmdshell "get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -AV-RISCVMSQL114 | Format-Table -Property DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size"
```

After executing this, I am getting error:

> 'get-WmiObject' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I want to execute this command in all SQL Servers. It's getting executed on SQL Server 2008, but on SQL Server 2012, it's throwing that error due to version or some PowerShell component is not installed.

Can you to please look at the code and let me know

Comment: [From the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh849824.aspx): `Starting in Windows PowerShell 3.0, this cmdlet has been superseded by Get-CimInstance.` It's most probably not available anymore in the PowerShell version you are using on the newer server.

Comment: so do i have to use  xp_cmdshell "get-ciminstance Win32_LogicalDisk -AV-RISCVMSQL114

Comment: `Get-WmiObject`is still available in PowerShell v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
xp_cmdshell 'PowerShell.exe -noprofile -command "get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -AV-RISCVMSQL114 | Format-Table -Property DeviceID,FreeSpace,Size"'
```

If this doesn't work logon to the server open `PowerShell` with administrator rights. Type `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and check that Execution Policy is set to Unrestricted. If it isn't then enter the following, then type 'A' (Yes to All):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

If this still doesn't work try upgrading to at least `PowerShell V3`. But if this is not possible you can try repair your corrupt `PowerShell V2` WMI repository with:

```
winmgmt /verifyrepository
```

If repository is found to be inconsistent run `Winmgmt /salvagerepository` and `Winmgmt /resetrepository` and verify after each. If it is still inconsistent try the following steps:

- Go to `Task Manager`>> Services >> Open Service >> `Windows Management Instrumentation` service, and change the start up type to `Manual`.
- Stop the WMI service:

  `net stop winmgmt`
- Rename the repository folder (`C:\Windows\System32\wbem\Repository`) to some else 'Repository_OLD'.
- Start the WMI service:

  `net start winmgmt`
- Set the service back to auto start.

Failing Re-register all of the `dlls` and recompile the `.mofs` in the `Wbem` directory with the following `.bat` script and then reboot.

```
@echo off
sc config winmgmt start= disabled
net stop winmgmt /y
%systemdrive%
cd %windir%\system32\wbem
for /f %%s in (‘dir /b *.dll’) do regsvr32 /s %%s
wmiprvse /regserver 
winmgmt /regserver 
sc config winmgmt start= auto
net start winmgmt
for /f %%s in (‘dir /s /b *.mof *.mfl’) do mofcomp %%s
```

Comment: after using above command Get-WmiObject : Not found 
At line:1 char:14
+ get-WmiObject <<<<  win32_LogicalDisk AV-RISCVMSQL114
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], Managemen 
   tException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C 
   ommands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Comment: What do you get when you run `xp_cmdshell 'PowerShell.exe -noprofile -command "Get-ExecutionPolicy"'` and `xp_cmdshell 'PowerShell.exe -noprofile -command "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"'`?

Comment: first output i get remote signed and other 2

Comment: unrestricted and 3

Comment: do i have to upgrade powershell version to 3 on server its not working

Comment: You should try `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` first (See answer), but upgrading to at least 3 wouldn't hurt.

Comment: i made it to unrestricted byt upgrading to powershell is not in my hands, will raise request and let you know

Comment: i ran winmgmt /verifyrepository it is giving me repository is inconsistent i tried stopping and starting winmgmt services but it doesnt work

Comment: Did you rename the repository?

Comment: its not allowing me to rename repository, saying folder or file is open in anothe rprogram

Comment: OK try `Winmgmt /salvagerepository`. Then if its still inconsistent try the `BAT` script at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Just a thought did you set the `WMI Service` start up type to manual before you stopped it and renamed it? As I think it will just restart if it on auto.